# Random matching without repeat

Tags: java, arrays, random

I've worked on the project in my school and stuck with an error. I cannot run this code since it has an error '`randA2` is already defined in method `main(String[])`' How can I fix it?

```
String [] A = {"Russia", "Saudi_Arabia", "Egypt", "Uruguay"};
int A1 = A.length;
int randA1 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
int randA2 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
int randA3 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
int randA4 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
while(randA1 == randA2) {
    int randA2 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
while(randA1 == randA3) {
    int randA3 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
while(randA2 == randA3) {
    int randA3 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
while(randA1 == randA4) {
    int randA4 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
while(randA2 == randA4) {
    int randA4 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
while(randA3 == randA4) {
    int randA4 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
String AnnounceA1 = A[randA1] +" " + "VS" + " " + A[randA2];
System.out.println(AnnounceA1);
String AnnounceA2 = A[randA3] +" " + "VS" + " " + A[randA4];
System.out.println(AnnounceA2);
```

Comment: don't use the type after the first declaration it should be `randA2 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);`

Comment: And just for the record: instead of using random indexes, it is much easier to use some library method to shuffle arrays randomly. Your code works, but basically it is broken for enhancement. Each time you want to add another string to your array ... the number of such checks multiplies. This doesn't scale. If at all, you should put the random indexes in some second array, and then ensure that the second array has only unique entries (then you can grow your arrays as you want, without ever writing more code)

Comment: You have also a logic issue. for example after `while(randA2 == randA3) {int randA3 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);}` randA1 and randA3 could be equal again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to use another way to solve your problem, all you need is :

```
String[] contries = {"Russia", "Saudi_Arabia", "Egypt", "Uruguay"};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(contries));

String announceA1 = contries[0] + " VS  " + contries[1];
System.out.println(announceA1);
String announceA2 = contries[2] + " VS  " + contries[3];
System.out.println(announceA2);
```

Comment: This is a good option, but the only problem is that it shuffles the original array, which maybe the OP does not want, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Another +1 for using reasonable naming! Maybe you make an explicit comment about that, too. `A` is just plain horrible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The questioner will soon discover that his approach doesn't scale. Each time he adds another country to that list, he has one more index to deal with. Even when he doesn't use shuffle directly, he needs to implement shuffling himself (by managing that index-map in a different way that doesn't depend on rolling out all the necessary comparisons between indexes)

Comment: To the OP as @GhostCat said,  the name of variables should be in lower case and should have be significant

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen an alternative to preserve original array ordering would be `List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3); Collections.shuffle(indexes);`, then `countries[indexes.get(0)]`, `counters[indexes.get(1)]` etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good option.  Shuffle was completely out of my head when I answered, so I won't update again :-)

Comment: @AndyTurner or `String[] contries = {"Russia", "Saudi_Arabia", "Egypt", "Uruguay"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(contries.clone());
Collections.shuffle(list);

String announceA1 = list.get(0) + " VS  " + list.get(1);
System.out.println(announceA1);
String announceA2 = list.get(2) + " VS  " + list.get(3);
System.out.println(announceA2);`

Comment: @YCF_L why need to `.clone()` ? because no matter no clone the list, it is the elments that will be added no ?

Comment: @azro based on the first comment by TimBiegeleisen I use `.clone()` to not lose the order of the original array

Comment: @YCF_L Do we matter to keep the order to apply `shuffle` after :D but okok

Comment: no @azro it doesn't matter It was just to answer TimBiegeleisen ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reassign a new value to a variable in Java, then you don't need to declare its type again.  So your first `while` loop should look like this:

```
while (randA1 == randA2) {
    randA2 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
```

But besides this, your code has a logical problem, and it won't actually generate 4 unique random numbers.  Actually, if you control which numbers you accept, they aren't really random.  I would go with this version:

```
String[] teams = { "Russia", "Saudi_Arabia", "Egypt", "Uruguay" };
Set<Integer> rands = new HashSet<>();

while (rands.size() < teams.length) {
    rands.add((int)(Math.random()*teams.length));
}

String AnnounceA1 = teams[rands[0]] +" " + "VS" + " " + teams[rands[1]];
System.out.println(AnnounceA1);
String AnnounceA2 = teams[rands[2]] +" " + "VS" + " " + teams[rands[3]];
System.out.println(AnnounceA2);
```

The strategy in my suggested version of your code is using a *set* to hold 4 random integers (which is the number of teams in your example).  It is a property of sets that every entry has to be unique.  So, if we iterate this set, adding random integers, we will eventually end up with 4 unique random integers.  Then, we can use them to choose team names to display in your output message.

Comment: @YCF_L There are bigger problems than this.  Updating in 2 minutes.

Comment: Could you quickly expand on what your second version actually does? It might be hard for a person new to Java to understand why there is a `while` loop and what a `Set` does (and why it solves the problem with having 4 unique random values)

Comment: @Ben Updating now.

Answer (score 0):

You redefine your vars inside the while loops.
Ommit the `int` declaration iside the while loops:

```
...
while(randA1 == randA2) {
    randA2 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
while(randA1 == randA3) {
    randA3 = (int)(Math.random()*A1);
}
...
```

Java is a type safety language. This is different to for example JavaScript. Inside JavaScipt the JIT (Just in time compiler) would not complain, because it is allowed to redefine variables, event if the type is changing.